# auto_increment in U-SQL

Tags: u-sql, azure-servicebus-queues

I am trying to form a new table that contains unique user_id's from existing one. Is it possible to add **auto_increment** primary key in U-SQL like we can add in MySQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate on David's answer: Unlike MySQL, ADLA/U-SQL is executed in a scale-out shared nothing architecture. Thus there is not an easy way to manage auto-incremental numbers.

However, there is are some tricks that you can use:

1. You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function to generate a number per row. You could add that to the MAX you have so far.
2. Or you could use `DateTime.Now.Ticks` to get an initial seed (plus some additional offset if you want to make sure you do not have overlapping ranges between different inserts) and the use `ROW_NUMBER()`.
3. Less recommended is the use of `NewGUID()`, since that generates a different guid and is not repeatable. Thus if a vertex is retried, it may fail the job due to non-determinism.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, I've got a related question but in regards to NewGuid within Extractors, I'd love to get your insight: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54269224/are-guids-unique-when-using-a-u-sql-extractor

Answer (score -1):

This is not currently possible.